# ReactJS: using spread element to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a syntax error and not sure I understand why:

Current state looks something like this:

```
people: [{
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Eric',
    lastName: 'Andrews',
}, {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Rick',
    lastName: 'Handsome',
}, {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Yoni',
    lastName: 'Andrews',
}],

addNewFriend() {
    this.setState({
        people: {
            [...this.state.people, {
                id: this.state.idIncrementor + 1,
                firstName: this.state.newPerson['newFirstName'],
                lastName: this.state.newPerson['newLastName'],
            }]
        },
        newPerson: ''
    })
}


Syntax error: Unexpected token (156:26)

  154 |         this.setState(
  155 |             {
> 156 |                 people: {[...this.state.people, 
      |                           ^
  157 |                     {
  158 |                         id: this.state.idIncrementor +1, 
  159 |                         firstName: this.state.newPerson['newFirstName'],
```

I want to merge the `this.state.people` and a new dictionary. `people` is current a list of dictionaries and I want to add a new dictionary.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `{[ ]}` is just invalid JavaScript. You cannot put an object literal inside an object literal like that. It has nothing to do with spread elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've missed that `people` is an array, not an object, so

```
people: {[...this.state.people,
```

should be

```
people: [...this.state.people,
```